# Save SSH session in PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm

Does anyone know how to save SSH session details in PhpStorm, so its just there when I open my project up? I love PhpStorm but its the only thing it doesn't seem to do, is it not an option or do I have to enable something?

Every time I want to do command line stuff I have to got to `Tools > Start SSH session` and the next dropdown is always "edit credentials" but I would like to save this so I don't have to enter my details each time.

[image]

Comment: add a sftp deployment option for the server you want to connect to

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Go to PHPStorm Settings > Search for 'Deployment' > Click on Add sign and follow the steps.

Once done, don't forget to 'Test sFTP Connection' if you are using SFTP. Then in Tools > Start SSH Session you will see your saved session.

Enjoy!!

Comment: Thanks Aneek, some one showed me a while back but forgot to to update this question. Cant believe I had to ask the question, I need to go back to school I think. Thank you for taking the time to help

Comment: Thanks ! It works fine ! This tip is not explained on the PhpStorm doc.